# Alternative to ICollections in SQLite

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin, error-handling

I am developing a cross-platform xamarin app using c#.

I have a funciton (with inheritance) like so:

```
 public class Medicine_Incident : Medicine 
    {
        // Whatever other stuff i have declared

        ...

        public virtual ICollection<Medicine_Incident> Medicine_Incident { get; set; }
     }
```

I came across an exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[LoginSystem.Models.Medicine]
```

I assume it is because of the ICollection line.

It is quite necessary for me to use ICollections as i am heavily reliant on this line of code:

```
medicine.Medicine_Incident.Add(med_inc);
```

Where,
`var med_inc = (Medicine_Incident)BindingContext;`

```
var medicine = (Medicine)BindingContext;
```

Now, if ICollections is truely not supported by SQLite (like it says here: [https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18548/dont-know-about-system-collections-generic-icollection-1][1])  What can i do and how can i change the IColections.Add method to comply with the new solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What about IList<T>  or List<T>?

Comment: It gives this: System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LoginSystem.Models.Medicine]

Comment: Which is basically the same error

Comment: Seems there's a bug with the latest release. Check this issue: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/553

Comment: Ahhh, i see, thanks a lot for bringing that up.